# Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric (Production, not debug/local)

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

Im just getting started with Windows Azure and have got a small MVC application running locally using the Azure emulator. I signed up for a free trial, downloaded my publishing profile and imported it into VS2012. Published to Azure and got some assembly reference errors. I resolved this by setting them to copy local = true and now i get:

```
    Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultStartupInfoForCurrentRoleInstance() +447
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener..ctor() +40

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.]
   System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType, String initializeData) +6792949
   System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() +45
   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() +83
   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() +143
   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners() +181
   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args) +155
   DotNetOpenAuth.Loggers.TraceLogger.Info(Object message) +26
   DotNetOpenAuth.Logger.CreateWithBanner(String name) +45
   DotNetOpenAuth.Logger..cctor() +14

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.Logger' threw an exception.]
   DotNetOpenAuth.Logger.get_Library() +14
   DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.Initialize() +410
   DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.set_Enabled(Boolean value) +31
   DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting..cctor() +285

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting' threw an exception.]
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +41

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting' threw an exception..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +550
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +90
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: The type initializer for 'DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting' threw an exception..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If seen this error if you are testing locally and have set the web project as the startup project rather than the cloud project, but as I say, this works fine locally against the emulator, but deploying into Azure causes this to fail.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Which project do you deploy? The Cloud project (to a cloud service) or the Web Application (to a Windows Azure Web Site)?

Comment: I would track down the dependencies of DotNetOpenAuth, and make sure they're all local.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the Windows Azure Role project as the "Startup" project. This solved my problem. I encountered the same issue when I set another webapp in the same solution as startup project.

Answer (score 55):

Try deleting the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener` trace listener configuration in your `web.config`. See this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10204672/175679). `DotNetOpenAuth.Logger` seems to conflict with WAD (*windows azure diagnostics*).

#### Remove trace listener from `web.config`:

```xml
<trace> 
    <listeners> 
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics"> 
            <filter type="" /> 
        </add> 
    </listeners> 
</trace>
```

Comment: This can also break unit tests causing the following error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Object reference not set to an instance of an object. or via mstest.exe: Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric..

Comment: Yep was having this issue as well and this did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up to people who follow this answer -> this has the side-effect of disabling the Azure diagnostics trace listener for the entire project (which might not be the solution you are looking for).