# Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric. Error in deployed version

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, diagnostics

I have Diagnostic trace listener on in my application deployed on web role.  Everything works fine in development environment when run through emulator. But I am receiving following error when deployed on azure
Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultStartupInfoForCurrentRoleInstance() +518
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener..ctor() +34

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.]
   System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType, String initializeData) +9004943
   System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() +110
   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() +989
   System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() +252
   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners() +331
   System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message) +161
   AVAWebApplication.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +28

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +581
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +179
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +384
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +397

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +678
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +810

Can Anybody please help ?

Answer (score 0):

DotNetOpenAuth.Logger seems to conflict with WAD (windows azure diagnostics). Also see this post: [Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric (Production, not debug/local)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879443/not-running-in-a-hosted-service-or-the-development-fabric-production-not-debug)

Remove trace listener from web.config:

```
<trace> 
    <listeners> 
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics"> 
            <filter type="" /> 
        </add> 
    </listeners> 
</trace>
```