# How can I log a message so that I can see it in VS2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am running a VS2013 Azure application locally and outputing a message to the Debug window like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(logString);
```

This works SOMETIMES and other times I get a message saying:

```
Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.
Could not create Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,     Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics,
```

From what I understand from other answers on SO there is some kind of conflict with the Diagnostics when I use Debug.Write().

So is there another way I can write a message to the output window just while I am testing? I know there is a Console.Write but this will not work as I do not have a console.

Comment: Make sure you set the cloud service project as startup project, not any role project as startup OR refer to this related SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13881495/122005).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using System.Diagnostics, you can use the trace object:

```
Trace.Write("YOUR MESSGE");
```

Here's a reference...

Comment: Where does the Trace output go to ?  How can I see that ?

Comment: on the Output window in visual studio

Comment: pres Ctrl+Alt+O to display it